# What is the space of this probability measure?

Tags: probability, group-theory, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I have a probability measure as follows:

$$
\rho(q)=\frac{1}{Z}\det \exp -\tau \mathbf{M}(q)
$$

where

$$
Z=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\det \exp -\tau \mathbf{M}(q)
$$

Where $\mathbf{M}(q)$ are in $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$.

I was able to establish that if $\mathbf{M}(q)$ is group isomorphic to the complex number, then a vector $\psi(q)$ such that $\rho(q)=\frac{1}{Z}\det \psi(q)$ are simply states of a complex Hilbert space, and the partition function is simply inner product of said space.

In the general case, the exponential $\exp -\tau \mathbf{M}(q)$ maps to the one-parameter group of the orientation-preserving general linear group $GL^+(n,\mathbb{R})$ (if $\mathbf{M}(q)$ is real) or the complex general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ (if $\mathbf{M}(q)$ is complex).

However, in the general linear case and unlike the complex case, $\psi(q)$ does not nicely fit into a either a vector space, or a Hilbert space, but it comes very close. My question is what structure does $\psi(q)$ lives in?

---